# Arrays in JavaScript as variable to store mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I want to create a two dimensional array in Reactjs. How can I declare this array as a variable? How do I push the elements in this array. I am new to React. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would probably be better to use a Map rather than an Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `fill` and `map` as below:

```js
const initialValue = -1
const rowsCount = 2
const colsCount = 3
const arr = new Array(rowsCount).fill(initialValue).map(() => new Array(colsCount).fill(initialValue))
// Now you can change value as we do it other languages like Java
arr[1][1] = 343453
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome :)